# How should I behave when a discussion starts in the comments of my answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, etiquette

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to find the value of a user created button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420522/how-to-find-the-value-of-a-user-created-button/54421531#54421531)

I've answered the question, and received a comment sustaining that my answer was incorrect that started a discussion.
I didn't want to discuss in the comments, but don't have the rep to chat, so we discussed in the comments, and after a lot of comments it seems we reached the end.

What is the correct behavior in this case?
Is it ok to 'chat a little' in the comments?
Should I just drop it even if I wanted to discuss?

In the end the discussion gave me more insight and I edited my answer, resulting in a better one.

Comment: When I read the title I thought this is when some other people discuss your answer's correctness or some off-topic things under your answer (i.e., it was not clear that the answer-poster participates in the discussion)

Comment: I'm not so good with the language, but I'll try to rephrase the title

Comment: Unless comments are off-topic or rude that's exactly [their purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/299295): to discuss question/answer above. I am writing this comment right now, because I think that link I posted is useful to read, but I don't think it adds much to accepted answer, so if its deleted no one in the whole internet will cry..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The comments actually served a valid purpose - they provided you with the guidance and instruction needed to improve your answer.

Mission accomplished on the part of the comments, but they have now outlived their usefulness.  I'd recommend to not engage much further, and possibly flag a moderator to remove them since they're no longer necessary; anything pertinent has already been captured in your answer and they only serve to clutter it up now.

In general it's not the *best* idea to chat back-and-forth in comments, but so long as a resolution comes about fairly quickly, I don't see that much of a problem...but it is important that the comments are removed fairly quickly afterwards.

Comment: "but it is important that the comments are removed fairly quickly afterwards." -> right. In any case, always assume that the comments can and will be suddenly deleted at some point. If there are interesting points that need to be incorporated in the answer / question, edit it to add the relevant information that arose from the chat .

Comment: Note that "flag a moderator to remove them" should **not** mean to use a custom flag. Simply flag the comments as "No longer needed" and let the system do the rest...That's precisely why that stock-flag exists

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the given answers in the comments . If the comments are technical and regarding your question then you should answer it properly and with full knowledge but if the people are not giving comments according to your question and giving non technical comments then you should avoid the conversation.

Comment: I don't get it. What does this have to do with comments appearing under an answer?

Comment: Are you getting your wires crossed here?  The comments the OP is referring to are in an answer and not the question.